# Extract location of string in Excel sheet using readtable

Tags: excel, matlab

I am writing a program that will use `readtable` to manipulate data that is read from an Excel spreadsheet such as the one below:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F...
1  "   "   "   "   "   "
2  "   S   3   K3  "   "
3  "   "   "   "   "   "
4  "   "   10  3C  "   "
5  "   G   7   U   "   "
6  "   "   "   "   "   "
.
.
.
```

I must extract the original location of some of the data, that is I need to store the location of `'S'` as `'B2'` and `'K3'` as `'D2'` etc. after they are read from the spreadsheet. To do this, I use `readtable`and then search for the location in the spreadsheet that contains the desired string; however, this requires that the entire spreadsheet be loaded into MATLAB.

I don't know in advance the number of empty rows or columns before `'S'`, nor do I know if some data will be filled in any of the columns in the rows above it. Additionally, I don't want the variable names to be generated automatically.

`readtable('FilePath', 'ReadVariableNames', false, 'Range', 'myrange')`

allows for not reading the variable names but doesn't allow for a dynamic range, i.e. the default option will skip the blank space and a specified range can't be dynamic.

```
opts=detectImportOptions('FilePath'); 
opts.DataRange='A1'
readtable('FilePath', opts, 'ReadVariableNames', false)
```

allows for specifying a start of the range but `opts=detectImportOptions` overwrites the `'ReadVariableNames'` option, and the program reads the variable names anyway. The only workaround that I found was to use `readtable` without `opts` and to specify a range larger than the largest anticipated data set and then to trim empty rows and columns, but this is slow and clumsy. Is there a workaround?

Comment: How are you creating `opts`? This question could use a minimal working example to make it clearer what the appropriate answer is for the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question, let me know if it's more clear now